PineScript: Get the IPO date of a ticker, and get the open prices of that ticker and SPY on that day
For example, I want to get the IPO day of NVDA (or the very first data in the history). Which was 1999-01-22 on TradingView. Then, get the open prices of NVDA and SPY on that day (1999-01-22). Which was 0.0438 and 122.13, respectively.

Note: When you read this, the open prices might be adjusted due to split or dividend.

Questions:

How to get the IPO day of a ticker?
How to get the open price of a ticker on a specific day?

The chart bars have a limitation: 5000 bars for free users. It means that the first bar of the chart's data might not be the first data of the entire history.
I just want to know the IPO day of a ticker, and the open prices of that ticker and other stock indexes. How to do that?

barstate.isfirst you can obtain the values ​​of the first bar in barset.
with the limitation of 5000 bars.
//@version=5
indicator('isfirst', overlay = true)

if barstate.isfirst
    log.info("\n{0}\nday: {1}\nmonth: {2}\nyear: {3}\nopen: {4}", syminfo.ticker, dayofmonth, month, year, open)



Thanks, but how to get the very first day in the historical data?
